# Multiplicative inverse ($17^{-1} \mod 31$)?

Tags: finite-field

So. Sorry for bothering you with such a simple question, but I can't really get this done.

It's just an exam question in which I need to use CRT in order to calculate the RSA signature of a msg m=101(dec), given RSA public modulus n=527=p*q=17*31.

So using CRT I need to calculate $p^{-1}\mod q$, which is, for the Euclidean Extended Algorithm, equal to $p^{\phi(q)-1} \mod q$. 
**Or in other terms $17^{-1}\mod 31 = 17^{29} \mod 31.$**

My exercise book shows a (imo) wrong result for this calculation. 
Can you please do the calculation (I used a Square&Multiply strategy) and tell me what you get? 
Also, is there any tool (online or not) which can help me doing fast MOD calculations like this one without having to do them manually?
Thanks in advance and sorry for the "useless" and "noobish" question.

Comment: $17^{-1}\bmod 31=11$. Does this help you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Did you do the calculation manually? Or did you use a tool?

Comment: as far as tools go, you may want to look for a CAS being able to do number and group theory related operations. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems#Functionality) for a list. Personally I use the outdated Derive 6, which isn't available any longer.

Comment: It's not hard to write the code to calculate the multiplicative inverse (as I did in [this answer to another question](/a/24779/18501)), but if you just want to calculate it one time for something you're working on, it's a built in function in various languages. For example, use `PowerMod[17,-1,31]` in Mathematica or [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PowerMod%5B17%2C-1%2C31%5D+). See more ways to do it [on RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse).

Comment: Use Extended Euclidean algorithm to the pair (17,31). Then you will get a Bezout identity $a17+b31=1.$ Take modulo 31 and you are done. The inverse is $a$.

Comment: Other ways to compute multiplicative inverses include adding 17 to itself and reducing modulo 31 until you reach 1, and then counting how many times you added 17. It's not the fastest way in the world, but it takes at most 30 additions and is simple to explain and see why it works.